# Expand image and navigation menu when page overflows

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, html

I have a website in which 2 pages the content overflows in small screens, meaning you have to scroll horizontally to view all the content. Because of this the menu and the logo image at the top of the screen gets cut off on those 2 pages. Both the menu and the logo are loaded by the Master Page. I tried fixing this issue by using media queries and assigning a specific width which did resolved the issue for those 2 pages but it caused all the pages to scroll on a small screen as that fix affected the Master Page. I thought this is a very basic problem but I surprisingly could not find any solution for this. I was wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to solve this.

Edit: Posted code from my Master page and Style file.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #ffffff;
    max-width: none;
    overflow: scroll;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 0px
}

td {
    padding: 2px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-spacing: 0px
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------Header Logo------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------------ Menu -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
.navbar {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
}

    .navbar a {
        float: left;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

.dropdown {
    float: left;
}

    .dropdown .dropbtn {
        font-size: 16px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-family: inherit;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .navbar a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
        background-color: red;
    }

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

    .dropdown-content a {
        float: none;
        color: black;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
    }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #ddd;
        }

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}


/*-----------------------------------------------------------------Formatting------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.
.under2 {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3A4A37;
}

.box_app {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #3A4A37;
    border: 1px solid #C4D0C1;
}

.validator {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #F00000;
}

.validator_mini {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #F00000;
}

.validator_mini2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000080;
}

.subtitles {
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #093145;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #3A4A37;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
}

.textbox_padded {
    border: 1px solid #C4D0C1;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #3A4A37;
    font-family: arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.title_times_new {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 32px;
    color: #4D6145;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
}

.title_times_new2 {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4D6145;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.contract_list {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}


/*-------------------------------------------------------------------New Contract Form----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#contract table {
    width: 600px;
}

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.img-responsive {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.drop {
    left: 0px;
    margin-right: 90px;
}

.flow {
    width: 1200px
}

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------Media queries----------------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
    .navbar {
        width: 1670px;
        margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .responsive {
        width: 1670px;
    }

    .contract_list {
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-left: 1%;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <link href="~/secure/styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" runat="server" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/secure/font-awesome.min.css" runat="server" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/ico" href="images/faviocon/favicon.ico" runat="server" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Logo" runat="server" class="responsive" />
        <div class="navbar" runat="server" style="margin-top: 0px; padding-top: 0px;">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn" causesvalidation="false">
                    Clinical Arrangements        
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/secure/student_ca_arrangement.aspx">Add New Student</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn" causesvalidation="false">
                    Contracts 
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/secure/ca_contracts/new_contract.aspx">New Contract</a>
                    <a href="/secure/ca_contracts/contract_list.aspx">Contract List</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropbtn" causesvalidation="false">
                    Letters 
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="/secure/letters/begin_letter_list.aspx">Beginning of Term Letter</a>
                    <a href="/secure/letters/end_letters_list.aspx">End of Term Letter</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a id="logout" causesvalidation="false" runat="server" onserverclick="logout_Click">Sign Out</a>
        </div>

        <br />
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.ywxi.net/js/1.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not going to get very helpful answers with no CSS or markup in your question.

Comment: @IrishChieftain done, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable horizontal scroll with

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

in your CSS

Comment: I actually want the horizontal scroll bar. Those 2 pages have tables that are displaying a lot of columns and data which is causing the overflow. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Actually I think I will just disable the scroll on all the pages that don't need it. It's not the most optimal solution as I will have to add that to every new page as the website grows but for now it will work. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah its not the most optimal, You could try to set percentage values / viewport values on your widths rather than fixed pixel values, also check the parent elements of your website in the chrome dev tools and see if you need to set percentage values on the parent elements as well

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're hand-rolling your own responsive media queries? I would suggest using Bootstrap v3 - you can use package manager to set the whole thing up.

In your media query you're setting a fixed width using pixels, to 1670px. In RWD, fixed units for width are never used; it's always done in percentages. You can avoid these issues by using Bootstrap since all the heavy lifting is already done for you.

In the case of your specific issue, you should have different media screens for the different screen resolutions:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-media-queries

Comment: I didn't think Bootstrap would be necessary because this website will not need to be mobile optimized. I used the fixed width just to align it with the table that is overflowing on those pages as the table widths never change no matter the screen resolution. Do media queries adjust a page based of whether or not it overflows?

Comment: I use Bootstrap on websites that are never used on mobile devices. It makes things much easier to manage either way, as you'll likely be accessing it from different screen sizes.

Comment: No. Media queries and the browser determine the layout based on viewport size. It sounds to me like your remedy is worse than the illness. I'd go back to scratch and set a container around everything ;-)